# Bash treating variable expansion as command while passing to other script

Tags: bash, shell

```
a=HDH b=udud c=jsjsj bash secondscript
```

The command above works. I'd like to save the assignments in a variable, like so:

```
value="\
    a=HDH \
    b=udud \
    c=ududj \
    "
$value bash secondscript
```

But it gives an error:

```
test.sh: line 9: a=HDH: command not found
```

Why? What can I do instead?

Comment: Assignments are identified before any expansion happens.

Comment: Ok so what should i do then ? Any workaround to achieve my goal

Comment: For an explanation of why you can't save assignments in a variable see my writeup here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61898254/how-can-i-create-a-bash-environment-variable-that-prefixes-an-environment-variab/61898307#61898307.

Comment: `eval $value bash secondscript`

Comment: @alecxs eval is working only when value is an array

Comment: i have tested with your example string/variable it works (at least on mksh). maybe you forgot quotes for spaces? https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVnn5.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash's taking first item `a=HDH` as a command, what you need is :

```
value=(
  "a=HDH"
  "b=udud"
  "c=ududj"
)
env "${value[@]}" bash secondscript
```