# Run variable containing variables (with space) as a command on Linux/bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to run a variable as a command on Linux. But this variable also has variables inside. Basically, I have the following:

```
CMAKE=cmake
GENERATOR="Unix Makefiles"
CMAKE_CONFIGURE_="$CMAKE -G \"$GENERATOR\""
```

when I echo it, it seems that I have what I want:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

However, when I try to run CMAKE_CONFIGURE_ as a command like so:

```
$CMAKE_CONFIGURE_
```

I have the following error:

```
CMake Error: Could not create named generator "Unix
```

It seems the string **$GENERATOR** is passed as two arguments because of the space.
How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Try executing your command like this `"$CMAKE_CONFIGURE_"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681848/bash-storing-a-command-in-a-variable-cmd-and-then-running-it-with-cmd-fails https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for the second link, eval did the trick!